# Moment object to datepicker

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I can't seem to find a way to convert a moment.js object to an input type date format. My object is stored in a mongo db:

```
_d: "2020-07-07T18:14:25.557Z"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
...
```

and what I've tried is

```
.then(response=>{
document.getElementById("lastCalibration").value = response.data.last_calib.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
...
document.getElementById("lastCalibration").value = response.data.last_calib.toDate();
```

none of these seem to work. Any help would be great!

Comment: May this help you : https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_input_date_value

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to create a new date object when you assign the value.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("lastCalibration").value = new Date(response.data.last_calib);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

`let dateValue = moment(response.data.last_calib.toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

> It should give you desired value as "2020-07-21"